# Creating Start and Stop Functions for MBProgressHUD

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, mbprogresshud

I am trying to create two functions. One to start a `progressHUD` and one to stop the `hud`. I am creating this inside an extension of `UIViewController`. The functions are below:

```
func startProgressHUD() {
    let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.label.text = "Loading"
}

func stopProgressHUD() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**The first function works fine when called -> the HUD starts.**
 However, **when I call the stop function, the HUD never stops.** According to the description, the hide function I call inside my stop function hides the top-most `HUD` in the view. I only have one `HUD` open in the view, but the `HUD` never stops.

If I use:

```
func stopProgressHUD() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.view, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I have no problem, but the `hideAllHUDs` **function is deprecated -> the warning states, 'store references when using more than one HUD per view'.**

**How do I get the HUD to stop?**

Comment: HUD.flash(.Success, delay: 2.0) its dismiss after 2 second

Comment: @GouravJoshi for MBProgressHud, you use the hide functions. There is no dismiss function.

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I am leaving the HUD on until my backend database sends down the required information and can't have it on a delay.

Comment: when you call stopProgressHUD() at that time put this code so its dismiss hud .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `spinningActivity` as a global variable in your `ViewController`. Anytime when a HUD is needed you can do `self.spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)`. And when you don't need it anymore, `self.spinningActivity?.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

Declare the MBProgressHUD Globally and then show and hide it. It will definitely work